# Batch file - directory traversal

Tags: batch-file

I am new to Windows batch scripting and this is what I am trying to do:

I have a folder filled with subfolders containing all sorts of files.  However, the subfolders each have a particular file (mysecret.txt) that I have to find and do an import/export sequence on a third-party application.  Don't mind the import/export sequence for now because I've already scripted and tested that.  My question is how to go about traversing the directories, locating the "mysecret.txt" file and doing my thing with the third-party application.

This is what I have so far:

```
for /r (C:\Path\to\folder) %%f IN (mysecret.txt) do call :importexport "%%f"
endlocal
goto :eof

:importexport
REM *** SOMETHING LIKE ****
myapplication.exe /import %%f
sleep 10
myapplication.exe /export %%f

:eof
exit
```

What I am confused on is the exact details of the `importexport` section and how do I use the `%%f` variable that is passed in?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with this and see if it works out for you

```
@echo off
for /r "C:\path\to\folder" %%f in (mysecret.txt) do call :importexport "%%f"
endlocal
goto :eof

:importexport
if not exist %1 goto :eof

echo Found %1 with content:
more %1
echo Importing..
myapplication.exe /import %1
echo Sleeping..
timeout /t 10 >nul
echo Exporting..
myapplication.exe /export %1
echo.
```

It's more verbose than it needs to be, just remove the extra more/echo lines if you want.

Here's the output:

```
Found C:\path\to\folder\subfolder1\mysecret.txt with content:
subfolder1 - mysecret.txt
Importing..
myapplication.exe /import C:\path\to\folder\subfolder1\mysecret.txt
Sleeping..
Exporting..
myapplication.exe /export C:\path\to\folder\subfolder1\mysecret.txt
Found C:\path\to\folder\subfolder1\subfolder1a\mysecret.txt with content:
subfolder1a - mysecret.txt
Importing..
myapplication.exe /import C:\path\to\folder\subfolder1\subfolder1a\mysecret.txt
Sleeping..
Exporting..
myapplication.exe /export C:\path\to\folder\subfolder1\subfolder1a\mysecret.txt
Found C:\path\to\folder\subfolder2\mysecret.txt with content:
subfolder2 - mysecret.txt
Importing..
myapplication.exe /import C:\path\to\folder\subfolder2\mysecret.txt
Sleeping..
Exporting..
myapplication.exe /export C:\path\to\folder\subfolder2\mysecret.txt
```

I added echo in front of myapplication.exe while I ran since I don't have that application.

Comment: A few tweaks needed. In the `for/r` statement, `C:\path\to\folder` and the parameter being delivered to the subroutine `%%f` should be `"quoted"` to guard against separators in the pathname. Consequently, the quotes may be removed from `%1` in the subroutine. The initial (but logically redundant) `if` in that routine should be replaced by `if not exist %1 goto :eof` allowing the remainder of the routine to be coded without the parentheses. The label `eof` should be removed. `cmd` undestands `goto :eof` (with the colon) to mean `end of physical file`. `sleep 10` should be `timeout /t 10 >nul`

Comment: I'd suggest you "un-quote" the CALL's argument right on the first line of the subroutine as not to confuse `myapplication` with a quoted argument, like this: `:importexport \n set arg=%~1`.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. For my learning though, could someone explain why my `:importexport` branch was incorrect and why the `if` statement was needed in the answer?

Comment: You used %%f which is local to your for-loop. The if statement is required since the for-loop returns all sub-folders regardless of whether or not your file exists. Just try to create an empty folder and do an echo before the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

here's something: (untested though.)

```
for /r (C:\Path\to\folder) %%f IN (mysecret.txt) do (
myapplication.exe /import %%f
ping localhost -n 3>nul
myapplication.exe /export %%f
)
endlocal
pause
exit
```

the script will traverse each subdirectory, executing the import and export sequences on each `myfile.txt` found. the %%f is the `myfile.txt`. and the ping replaces the `sleep` part.
hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /r "C:\Path\to\folder" %%f IN (mysecret.txt) do if exist "%%~ff" (
        myapplication.exe /import "%%~ff"
        >nul ping -n 11 localhost 
        myapplication.exe /export "%%~ff"
    )
```

- The path indicated in the `for /r` as the starting folder does not use parenthesis, but quotes
- When indicating an string in the `(set)` part of the `for /r`, if the string does not contain a wildcard, all the **folders** under the indicated starting point (or the current folder if no initial path indicated) will be enumerated with the **string** appended. So, the code tests for file existence before processing.
- As `sleep` is not a native windows command, I have replaced it with an equivalent wait using `ping`. If you can use `sleep` or `timeout` commands, there is no need for the `ping`
- All file references are quoted to prevent problems with spaces or special characters in paths.